# Updating View of AlertDialog from Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog, fragment, android-alertdialog

I am not sure why I cannot update the `imageView` of a custom `dialog layout xml` which is opened from inside a `fragment`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setView(R.layout.qr_code_layout_dialog);
imageFromLayout.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
builder.show();
```

I have also tried to use a `Dialog` object (not AlertDialog) but it will not even open, therefore `AlertDialog` opens but will not show any images. Nor will it allow me to update the images from within the java code.

How can I update the `imageView` image of the `layout dialog` from within the fragment?

Comment: May be you can try the image loader libraries.

Comment: You are passing a layout resource int in the `setView` & setting a bitmap on an `ImageView` that may not be attached to the dialog's window.

Comment: How do I attach the ImageView to the dialog? Especially when it is already defined in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try make realisation of it

```
abstract class ObservableDialog<T>(private val callBack: (T) -> Unit): DialogFragment(){

companion object{
    const val TAG = "MY_TAG"
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setLayoutParam()
}

fun doMyChoice(obj: T){
    callBack(obj)
    dismiss()
}

private fun setLayoutParam(){
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
}

}
```

Call it like

```
val dialog = ObservableDialog<String>{
    //do something with result
    }
dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, ObservableDialog.TAG)
```